# elementsForName method of GDataXML not found .. but its in the header file etc

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, gdata

Im using GDataXML to do XML parsing etc in XCode 4.  The example I'm following requires use of a method called elementsForName.  I can see this method in the GDataXMLNode.h and .m, and Im including GDataXMLNode.h in my header file.  Im calling it like this :

```
- (GDataXMLElement *)elementForChild:(NSString *)childName {
    NSArray *children = [self elementsForName:childName];    //<---- prog hangs here 
    if (children.count > 0) {
        GDataXMLElement *childElement = (GDataXMLElement *) [children objectAtIndex:0];
        return childElement;
    } else return nil;
}
```

I dont believe its this code itself thats wrong - for some reason it just wont find the elementsForName method there.

I've added usr/include/libxml2 to the header search paths. Can anyone see or imagine a reason why I cant use a method that seems to be there?  Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this is an old question but I believe that all you have to do is format the `childName` argument as a string like so:

```
 @"childName"
```